# Using a Shared HTTPWebRequst Property

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to change the URI of a HttpWebRequest after it's been set? I only ask because if you see my code below I am setting the CookieContainer, and the UserAgent. If I was to set the shared client property to a new instance of a HttpWebRequest later in the code would I have to reset the UserAgent and CookieContainer?

The reason I wanted a shared HttpWebRequest property is so that I don't have to set these variables each time I make a request.

```
public MyAPI(String username, String password)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    this.cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    this.client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.com/api");
    this.client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0";
    this.client.CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer;
}

private async Task<bool> initLoginTokens()
{
    using (WebResponse response = await client.GetResponseAsync())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        CsQuery.CQ dom = CsQuery.CQ.Create(stream.ReadToEnd());

        tt = dom.Select("input[name='tt']").Attr("value");
        dn = dom.Select("input[name='dn']").Attr("value");
        pr  = dom.Select("input[name='pr']").Attr("value");

        if (tt == null || dn == null || pr == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public async Task<string> LoginAsync()
{
    if(! await initLoginTokens())
    {
        // Throw exception. Login tokens not set.
    }

    // Here I need to make another request, but utilizing the same HTTPWebRequest client if possible.
}
```

Comment: IIRC, a HttpWebRequest can only be used for one request and not reused for further requests. Unless you have a good reason to use HttpWebRequest directly, I'd recommend that you use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) (≥.NET 1.1) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) (≥.NET 4.5) instead, which both provide a nice interface that takes care of creating HttpWebRequests as needed and can be used for multiple requests.

Comment: Interesting regarding HttpClient I didn't even know it existed. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the request URI cannot be changed once set. Its readonly. You will have to re-initialize your variable.